# Azure is tidyup after deleting VM needed?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I deleted my one Azure VM and then created a new one (so should only be 1 in total, and its the only Azure thing I made). Now I have two lots of "availability set", "public IP" and "load balancer", one set with same number suffix as new VM and a second set with a different number. My guess is that second lot are leftovers after deleting old VM. I wonder if I am being charged for them? Please, can I delete them safely without disrupting the new VM?
Screenshots from Azure here[image]
[image]

Comment: No problem! If you find an answer helpful, it's also good to mark it as an answer so that others that come with the aame question in mind find it in your post. It helps the community grow, helps you and me too:). Also, you shouldn't post an answer as a reply to someone, a moderator will delete it at some point. Answers are specifically for others to answer your question or for you to provide an update in terms of solution you found on your own. I'm also new to SO, made the same mistakes and still learning! Cheers mate.

Comment: Oh and if you want reply to someone to answered, you should use do it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

**Cost of unused resources**

Not all resources are charged even when they are not in use.

1. [Availability sets are completely free](http://There%20is%20no%20cost%20for%20the%20Availability%20Set%20itself,%20you%20only%20pay%20for%20each%20VM%20instance%20that%20you%20create.).
2. [Public IPs are charged an hourly fee](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/pricing/details/ip-addresses/).
3. Basic Loadbalancers are free but Standard Loadbalancers are paid.

You can use the [Azure Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) to check the cost of each resource.

**Removing unused resources**

When you delete an Azure VM, Azure shows you a disclaimer:

> The action will permanently delete the virtual machine 'vmname'. Associated resources (disks, virtual networks, etc) will not be deleted and can be removed manually. Do you want to continue?

Azure doesn't automatically delete those associated resources because it assumes you might want to keep the disk to attach with another VM, or you might want to keep the Network Interface Cards etc.

If you are unsure whether they are in use, you can verify if the disks ([verify unattached disks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/find-unattached-disks)) and NICs ([verify unattached NIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/find-unattached-nics)) are unattached from any VM.

As for the Load Balancer, make sure you modify the rules/backend pools and validate that everything still works on your application. Once you're confident it's not in use, you can delete the resources.

For Public IPs, same logic. You can click on the Public IP and look at the `associated to` field. If it's empty - it's not in use.